# Unit Testing Spring Data JPA Repositories with Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, unit-testing, jpa, repository

I have a Spring Data JPA repository, and the unit tests work fine, as long as the Spring Security dependency (spring-boot-starter-security) is not added, with corresponding method authorization annotations on the repository.  Once added I get an AuthenticationCredentialsNotFound exception when running the unit test.

How do I "Authenticate" calls to repository methods in the unit test?

Comment: what authentication do you use? OAuth2?

Comment: Right now I'm just using basic authentication and I have repository methods annotated with `@PreAuthorize` annotations.

Answer (score 2):

I found an example of what to do here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/security/src/test/java/example/springdata/jpa/security/SecurityIntegrationTests.java

My tests run fine now as long as prior to calling methods on the repository, I first authenticate the user that has the required role like this:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
    .setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        "admin",
        "password",
        Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))));

// Make calls to repository methods that require the admin role
```

Answer (score 2):

Also in case you need to authenticate set more than one role (Courtesy of Rob Winch - Spring Security Lead):

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
    .setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        ADMIN,
        PASSWORD,   
        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
));
```